# Many photons, one quantum field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

If a photon can be described as an excitation in a quantum field, is this the same field for all photons, or does each photon exist in its own field?

Answer (score 5):

I believe it is the same field for all photons in the universe. Similarly there is one field for all up quarks in the universe, another field for all down quarks in the universe and so on for each particle type. In this way the field theory model explains the uncanny consistency of particles; a neutrino made in a supernova millions of miles away is identical (as far as we can tell) to the same species of neutrino created on Earth. This suggests that all neutrinos come from the same 'stuff', and we call this stuff the neutrino field.

I think David Tong mentions as much in this talk:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yplCob7_Ck

Comment: +1 This is good, but to be quite frank. No one knows what the correct answer to this question is. It is definitely true that it is the same type of field, but it is impossible to say for sure if it is the same field. Especially if we consider photons outside our visible horizon.

Comment: I'd say that's a fair comment. Maybe it's more accurate to say that in most applications we work with the assumption that all photons belong to the same field but that this isn't experimentally verified for all reaches of space. I've only recently been getting to grips with field theory so I appreciate such input.

Comment: I think if someone is asking a question about photons in quantum field theory, we can implicitly assume they are referring to the standard model of particle physics. Within the standard model, there is only one photon field.

Comment: @levitopher: You implicitly assume superpositions of photon states. How about mixtures which are not superpositions?

Comment: @Jim: It must be the same photon field. Otherwise you'd need an uncountable number of unrelated couplings to different photon fields.

Comment: @Neuneck and you don't think the vastly complex and mathematically perfect universe is capable of that?

Comment: @Jim: It would require an infinite ammount of fine tuning. For example by your many-fields reasoning every electron could have an arbitrary charge. On the other hand, the experiments tell us that all electrons have _exactly_ the same charge which would be an enormous coincident. Occhams razor therefore demands that we choose the most economic solution that is in accord with all observations. And that is that there is one single field for each particle type.

Comment: @Neuneck you make a valid point. Well played, sir.

Comment: @Neuneck Why would many fields require that every electron would have arbitrary charge? For now lets assume (for simplicity of discussion) that there is one field - corresponding to all electrons we've seen experimentally - and only one other field in a far off corner of space which we've not observed yet. Would this far off field arbitrarily affect the charges of electrons we see here on Earth? If so how does it do that? I thought the point Jim was making was that there may be one or more field so far away (perhaps beyond the observable universe), that don't effect measurements made thus far.

Comment: @Neunech Sorry for re-opening this discussion, I just want to make sure I understand the points that have been made.

Comment: @SirajRKhan: The field from far away would not affect our electrons. It could have an arbirary charge though, say $\sqrt{\pi}$ or $35$. If there were as many fields as there are electrons in the universe, the probability of their charges (which are unrelated, as they are unrelated fermionic fields) all being exactly equal is basically zero. Especially since no first principle sigles out charge $1$ (there are charge $\frac{1}{3}$ quarks).

Comment: @Neuneck Ah I see: So what you're saying is that if some distant field did exist, there's no reason for it to necessarily have the charge of an electron. If it doesn't have charge -1, we couldn't even call it an electron field. Therefore many electron fields (all charge -1) is too much of a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

Probability of photon emission by an atom depends on the occupation number of already existing photons of this sort. The corresponding occupation number is determined with the "boundary conditions". We cannot take the occupation number of all existing photons in the Universe, so time-space "separated" regions have effectively their own photon fields and their own occupation numbers.

On the other hand, when we observe an interference pattern, we don't care of the possible sources. To us it is crucial to have a photon at the same time at the same place whatever is its origin. Superposition happens for photons of a given sort arriving at the same time at the same place. That means the boundary conditions may be "open" for two or more sources.

Comment: The commutation relations look something like $[a(x),a^\dagger(y)]=\delta (x-y)$ right? We don't need another label $a_i$ to denote which part of spacetime (say use a partition of unity or something) "each field" is. My impression is "one quantum field" is the more usual interpretation.

Comment: @levitopher: How about loss of interference due to retardation of photons? Loss of coherence must be described somehow. Randomness of wave phases is a mean to "label different fields".

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski Would it not be correct to say that this approach of using multiple fields is more of a useful tool rather than a strict statement about the number of fields involved. Strictly speaking wouldn't we say that there is one photon field? However because the 1 field approach is too difficult (knowing the occupation number of all existing photons is too difficult) we work with the pretence of multiple fields. In this way we still get accurate answers, but via a much easier (and more possible!) method.

Comment: @user15766: Yes, it is still possible to deal with one field, but very complicated one due to too many sources/absorbers. The boundary conditions I mentioned are approximate (simplified) solutions to the total field-matter equations. So we replace one total field with many similar ones acting each in different places of Universe (i.e., without interference).

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski I see, thank you for the response. I'm learning a lot on this particular web page!

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the Hamiltonian of an electromagnetic field in a finite region of space. It is possible to find a suitable unitary transformation to change it in a form same as a Hamiltonian of a independent harmonic oscillators. A photon is a quantum of energy of such an ensemble of independent oscillators. All excitations of this ensemble will be associated with the same field.